# I have inserted in a table and with insert_id I wanted to get that row back but it's not happening?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

Below are my codes:

```
    //In one of my model(name is commonmodel) I wrote
    public function create_and_get($table,$data){
    $this->db->insert($table,$data); //It's okay
    $lastid= $this->db->insert_id();
    $getback=$this->db->get($table,array('id'=>$lastid))->result_array();
    return $getback[0];
```

In controller---basically it's a ajax call so..

```
    $stored=$this->commonmodel->create_and_get('party',$data);
    echo json_encode($stored); exit;
```

When in ajax response i call..

```
    var obj=$.parseJSON(res) //I get the object at console.log(obj)
    //but it's the first row every time from the 'party' table..
```

I'm so damned with this error and some other id hacks...Please help..

Comment: Are you sure that A) the insert happened, and have you checked the status of the $lastid = $this-db->insert_id() line? Could var_dump($lastid) - my guess is its 0

Comment: Yeah my console shows me..and Nah.. The last_id was correct but I dont know why its returning first row each time.. I cross checked but no luck..

Comment: Then it would be a problem with your db->get() controller. OR, if the ID field on the table is not a unique, auto-increment field, you may have multiple rows with the same ID value, and the ->get() call will get the first one found.

Comment: @Rottingham: Thanks brother I have solved that.. You r right. actually I used db->get($table, array('col'=>'val'))---which was wrong.. it should have been db->get_where($table, array('col'=>'val')) . Thank you anyway brother..

Answer (score 0):

I know you have worked it out, but i think it's a better solution to just return the data you used for the insert instead of querying the db again for it.

Something like this would work:

```
public function create_and_get($table,$data) {

    $this->db->insert($table,$data); 
    $lastid = $this->db->insert_id();
    $data['id_field_name'] = $lastid;
    return $data;

}
```

This will save you another trip do the DB.